# PDFSharp with Chinese characters

Tags: c#, pdf, character, pdfsharp

I have problem with displaying Chinese characters in PDFSharp in C#. During process of creating the PDF string it's ok, but after creating pdf file it doesn't display it. I found one solution which is

```
XFont font_small2 = new XFont("微软雅黑", 9, XFontStyle.Regular, options)
```

This solutions works on my localhost but when I release this on beta server it doesn't display Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed original Chinese font into your pdf file and use correct CMAP.

```
var options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
var font = new XFont("微软雅黑", 9, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

OR

```
var page = new PdfPage();
var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
gfx.MFEH = PdfFontEmbedding.Automatic;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the font is installed correctly on the beta server and make sure application has sufficient rights. Make sure the font is embedded in the PDF file.

According to the PDFsharp FAQ, CJK fonts are not supported. But still you should get the same results on server and local computer if the environments are set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the solutions worked for a newer version of the lib, so I came up with a workaround on drawing chars to a bitmap, then adding the bitmap to a PDF:

```
        Font font = GetFont(fieldInfo, fontSize * 0.97f); // Chosen empirically
        using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Draw string as an image
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap((int) fieldRect.Width, (int) (fieldRect.Height * 1.5f)))
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
                graphics.DrawString(fieldValue, font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty);
                bitmap.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            }

            // Draw image on PDF
            using (XImage xImage = XImage.FromStream(imageStream))
            {
                double labelPositionX = fieldRect.X1 + 2;
                double labelPositionY = fieldRect.Y2 - 2;
                xGraphics.DrawImage(xImage, labelPositionX, page.Height - labelPositionY);
            }
        }
```