# Japanese characters with MigraDoc/PDFsharp

Tags: c#, unicode, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using MigraDoc for generating PDF documents, on my local machine. Japanese characters are not displayed properly.

I'm using the instructions below to generate the document with Unicode.

```
var document = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
//Do stuff...
PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
renderer.Document = document;
```

This works well for some non ASCII characters (accentuated letters), but not with Japanese characters.

From the examples on PDFsharp's website, I think I'm supposed to use a PdfDocument (and not a Migradoc document) objects, add pages to that document, and fill pages with Migradoc objects

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx

However, I already have a complex, multipage document structure created with Migradoc; so I'd like to be able to just reuse it as it is (e.g. include it in one go into a PdfDocument)

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
document.Styles[StyleNames.Normal].Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS";
```

It is also possible to embed fonts in the PDF document, to make sure everybody can read it

Comment: So the trivial answer is: Japanese characters will show up only if you use a font that has Japanese characters. Setting the font for the Normal style is one way to achieve this. I cannot read Japanese so I do not know if that is all that is needed. Maybe the FAQ should be updated if that really is all.

Comment: In my application, Japanese characters are only displayed in tables, as row labels. I can't read Japanese either, but maybe if I needed to write paragraphs, which would read from right to left, this would not work. Maybe that's what the doc means

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FAQ](http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx) Japanese is not yet supported. Left-to-right languages are supported, Hebrew works if you reverse the strings.

With respect to Japanese characters it should make no difference whether you use MigraDoc (class `Document`) or PDFsharp (class `PdfDocument`).

Comment: From this answer, even if it's not officially supported, it seems that i can still work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746920/pdfsharp-with-chinese-characters

Answer (score 0):

I really wanted to use PDFSharp. But they say they do not support CJK or Arabic but I found out differently. I did look into this myself today and found a very simple way to accomplish all languages. Its the poor mans way but it works.

```
// Set font encoding to unicode always
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
// Then use the font with the most language support
XFont font = new XFont("Arial Unicode MS", 12, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

Now use this font when rendering text. I was able to test English, German, Arabic, Chinese, Korean, Japanese, Italian, Russian, Dutch and then decided I did enough for my testing.

Interesting side effect of embedding text if VS2010, with Arabic the most cursor works backward. OK will it the right way for Arabic. Awesome Microsoft.

Comment: Tried it with Hindi and it was sometimes adding extra characters in between words and sometimes linking words together.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, as 'Arial Unicode MS' isn't available by default with Windows 10, and the software I'm working on has to be distributed to computers with only default Windows 10 installed, so this fix won't work.

Simple fix:
Use "Dengxian" instead. It's not as good looking as Arial, so if you still want to use Arial for non-japanese versions of your software, simply check if the current UI culture is Japanese, and choose either 'Dengxian' or 'Arial' based on that.

There are other fonts too to choose from, here's where I identified available fonts from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows?oldformat=true

**Alternatively:**
You can embed the Arial Unicode MS font into the PDF document. See: [Azure PDF Sharp not using Unicode font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913079/azure-pdf-sharp-not-using-unicode-font/32980927#32980927) - This is the solution I went with in the end.